# Forefront Identity Manager location

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile, forefront

I have to delete a filter on the UserProfile-AD connection.
I can not delete it from interface (from central admin).
I know it is possible to do it from the **Forefront Identity Manager Client**.
But I can not locate it on the server.
I am using SharePoint Server 2013.
I already checked in the folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Location of the FIM Client(MIISClient.exe) is

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell
```

You should use the client from the server where Profile Synchronization is configured.

Comment: The folder Synchronization Service is missing. (I am looking on the single Front-End server, there are no Application Servers)

Comment: how many server in the farm? also check from Central admin > manage services in far> on this page check on which server sync service is running.

Comment: Is a dev environment so has just one front-end (where the User Profile Synch Service) is running and one sql back.end

Comment: did you install sharepoint on default location i.e c:\program file or you used some custom location i.e D or E drive? also from server go the services console and click on the "FIMSynchronizationService" take the properties and check the location.

Comment: The location was not the default :/ thanks for the advice!

Comment: here you go...enjoy.